# Getting the last part of a dynamic text?

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get the last part from dynamic text strings. for example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/OMG/9051284874
```

Here i will need to get the `9051284874` part, I was thinking about `preg_match`.

Something like `preg_match("@^(?:https://www.facebook.com/pages/OMG/)?([^/]+)@i", $results, $at);` while `$results` is the dynamic string but the `OMG` part is dynamic also so it will not work.

Basically what i need is to get the part after the LAST slash (`/`), any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple line (**without regexp**):

```
$lastPart = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
```

or even better to ensure this line will not fails if the char '/' isn't in the string:

```
if ( ($pos = strrpos($url, '/') ) !== FALSE)
   $lastPart = substr($url, $pos + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the trailing portion is always numerical, then

```
if (preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $url, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$url  = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/OMG/9051284874";
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$last = $pieces[count($pieces) - 1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should parse the url with `parse_url()`. This will return an associative array containing:

```
Array
(
[scheme] => http
[host] => www.facebook.com
[path] => /pages/OMG/9051284874
)
```

You can then `explode($parsedUrl['path'])` or use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('`/([^/]+)/[^/]*$`', $parsedUrl['path'], $paths);
```